# LD_PRELOAD_PATH for 32bits application on 64bits environment

Tags: linux, ld

I am on a 64bits linux running an application which is compiled for 32bits and have some libs in its directory.
So I do:

```
export LD_PRELOAD_PATH=./
./my_app
```

Still, I get errors of not finding the lib.

Is there other variable name for 32 bits libs search path?

Ps: I am sure I am not the first one to ask that, but I couldnt fint it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, preload is a different beast.